# How to exclude more than one character in rule?

Tags: string, antlr, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to write a string matching rule in ANTLRWorks, and I need to match either escaped quotes or any non quote character. I can match escaped quotes but I'm having trouble with the other part: `~'\'' | ~'\"'` will end up matching everything and `~'\'\"'` seems to be ignored by the grammar generator (at least the visual display). What sequence of characters will get me what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
StringLiteral
    :    '"' (EscapeSequence | StringChar)* '"'
    ;

EscapeSequence
    :    '\\' ('"' | '\\')
    ;

StringChar
    :    ~('"' | '\\')
    ;
```

Comment: I ended up going with a non-greedy anychar consumption, but this ought to do nicely to answer the question.